# Getting the total hours in a TimeSpan

Tags: c#, timespan

How can I subtract two dates and get the total hours of the `TimeSpan` object that is returned?

For example, if the TimeSpan is 2 days, the total hours are 48.

Comment: Isn't that just the TotalHours property of the TimeSpan, i.e. `(Date1 - Date2).TotalHours`? Or do I misunderstand the question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Then you want the [`TotalHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours.aspx) property of the [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) object:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime twoDaysAgo = today.AddDays(-2.0);

// returns 48.0
double totalHours = (today - twoDaysAgo).TotalHours;
```

Comment: Can't help but notice that, although this compiles and runs, there are some gotcha's re: TimeZones.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

```
int day = Tempo.Days;
int Hours = Tempo.Hours;
if (day > 0)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < day; i++)
  {
    Hours += 24;
  }
}
string minuto = (Tempo.Minutes < 9) ? "0" + Tempo.Minutes.ToString() : Tempo.Minutes.ToString();
string segundos = (Tempo.Seconds < 9) ? "0" + Tempo.Seconds.ToString() : Tempo.Seconds.ToString();
string texto = Hours.ToString() + ":" + minuto + ":" + segundos;
```

Comment: Overengineered, use `.TotalHours` or `.ToString(String)` instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings