# How to get the total hours with different dates in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

This is my problem now, i want to get the total hours and mins of work.
example from jan. 11 2017 22:00 to Jan. 12 2017 7:00.
so far i have it only work when the end date is not change

```
DateTime pin = today, pout = DateTime.Parse(empTime);
TimeSpan spanMe = pout.Subtract(pin);

spanMe.Hours
spanMe.Minutes
```

it gives me negative numbers.

Comment: `it gives me negative numbers.` <= That is expected if you subtract a larger item from a smaller item (ie. subtracting a more recent time from an older time). If you always want to see the difference as a positive number and do not want to take into account which is larger then wrap the result of the properties (like .Hours) in `Math.Abs` (absolute value).

Comment: You should use the`TotalHours` (or `TotalMinutes`) property

Comment: for example jan. 11 2017 @ 7:00 to 22:00 it gives me the correct total number of hours and mins. but from 10pm of jan. 11 to 7am to jan 12 there error come.

Comment: @stuartd where in the time timespan?

Comment: [Obligatory link to "time is hard" question.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6841333/1195056)

Comment: im missing the yesterdays time. DateTime Yesterday = pin.AddDays(-1.0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work :

```
            DateTime pin =  DateTime.Parse("jan 11 2017 22:00");
            DateTime pout = DateTime.Parse("Jan 12 2017 7:00");

            TimeSpan spanMe = pout.Subtract(pin);

            Console.WriteLine("Hours : {0}, Minutes : {1}", spanMe.Hours, spanMe.Minutes);

            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: how can i add the date and the time?

Comment: Adding Date to timespan doesn't make a lot of sense unless you are looking for end of the time span.  What you propbably want is     spanMe.TotalMinutes();

Comment: im going to choose this as answer because of the code i made i similar to this.

Answer (score 3):

> it gives me negative numbers.

That is expected if you subtract a larger item from a smaller item (ie. subtracting a more recent time from an older time). If you always want to see the difference as a positive number and do not want to take into account which is larger then wrap the result of the properties (like .Hours) in [Math.Abs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.abs(v=vs.110).aspx) (absolute value).

```
var hours = System.Math.Abs(spanMe.Hours);
var minutes = System.Math.Abs(spanMe.Minutes);
```

Also as pointed out by @stuartd there is a difference between [Hours](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.hours(v=vs.110).aspx)/[Minutes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.minutes(v=vs.110).aspx) and [TotalHours](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours(v=vs.110).aspx)/[TotalMinutes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes(v=vs.110).aspx). Make sure you are using the correct one for your needs.

Comment: this gives me 16hrs difference.

Comment: @Denver - The computer will not lie or make a mistake, if 16 is coming back as `.Hours` in the TimeSpan difference between your dates then there are 16 hours in between. Check your logic and check your actual `DateTime` instances to make sure they actually are what you think/assume they are.

Comment: @Denver - also check the `DateTime` instances [Kind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind(v=vs.110).aspx) component, subtracting an instance with value `DateTimeKind.Local` from `DateTimeKind.Utc` (as example) could produce an unexpected result.

Comment: thats why it's giving me the 16hrs because it count from 10pm to 7am i miss the yesterdays time which is ive seen it in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023514/getting-the-total-hours-in-a-timespan

Comment: thank you for the idea. math.abs remove the negative perfectly. ill give this a +1

Answer (score 0):

if you know what is the latest date, you need arrange it accordingly. If not, you can not multiply by -1:

```
double GetHouers(DateTime one, DateTime another)
{
    var diff = (one - another).TotalHours;
    return diff > 0 ? diff : diff * -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract one DateTime Object from another, and then use `.TotalHours` property of the DateTime class to get the number of hours. It will give you a double value representing the total hours.

```
DateTime pin = today, pout = DateTime.Parse(empTime);
double hours = (pout - pin).TotalHours;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime pin = today, pout = DateTime.Parse(empTime);
TimeSpan spanMe = pin.Subtract(pout);

var hours = spanMe.TotalHours;
var minutes = spanMe.TotalMinutes;
```

You want to use `TotalHours` and `TotalMinutes` as these will handle fractions thereof, versus `Hours` and `Minutes` which return only whole values. You also need to swap the order of your operands as above for the subtraction step.